# Are the rules about questions ban different for SO and for other sites?

Tags: support, post-ban, help-center

[In SO help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) I found a section *Does the ban last forever?* which says about question bans that: "If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated."

However, randomly trying some SE sites, I did not find the same sentence in help center. (I tried 
[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), 
[Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans),
[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), 
[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans),
[Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans),
[Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans),
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans),
[ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/question-bans), ...)

So are the rules for SO and other sites indeed different? Or is this information simply missing in the help center on other SE sites?

Comment: Just to confirm: none of the other help centers say that, as you can see by [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chance+to+ask+a+new+one+6+months%22).

Comment: [D'oh!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'oh!) I should have tried that instead of checking help centers of random sites. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It didn't matter until today, because this wasn't enabled on most sites. Not anymore: [Comprehensive question quality blocks now enabled everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291142/comprehensive-quality-blocks-now-enabled-everywhere)

I've updated the help page to reflect this.

Comment: Does the 6 month aspect of this feature apply to a website like Superuser which already question bans?

Comment: It applies everywhere, @Ramhound (and has since its inception, we just didn't bother updating the page anywhere else since we're lazy). Note that the ban *does not lift after six months* - you just get the chance to ask at most one more question, which *may* affect your eligibility for the ban if it's a good one.

Comment: I might have worded it wrong but I actually was wondering about that one question after 6 months, good to hear, it always applied